# Docker: Access JSON file via .ENV file

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform

I am currently trying to set up Google Cloud inside my Jupyter notebook. The whole setup is done with Docker.

.env (see [here](https://cloud.google.com/natural-language/docs/quickstart-client-libraries?authuser=1))

```
GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="[PATH]"
```

My Dockerfile currently looks like that:

```
FROM jupyter/scipy-notebook
RUN conda install --yes -c conda-forge fbprophet

ENV PATH "$PATH:/home/jovyan/.local/bin"
RUN pip install awscli --upgrade --user

# Install from requirements.txt file
COPY requirements.txt /tmp/
RUN pip install --requirement /tmp/requirements.txt && \
    fix-permissions $CONDA_DIR && \
    fix-permissions /home/$NB_USER
```

Now I tried to add `COPY Natural-Language-96a3b12743a0.json .` to my Dockerfile. However, I always get `chgrp: changing group of 'Natural-Language-96a3b12743a0.json': Operation not permitted`

The .ENV file I changed to the following: `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="Natural-Language-96a3b12743a0.json"`

But when I run the code in my Python noteboook I always see `DefaultCredentialsError: File "Natural-Language-96a3b12743a0.json" was not found.`

Do you see what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

If you already create the service account with the correct permission and downloaded the .json file.

Try adding permissions on the file

> sudo chmod 755 Natural-Language-96a3b12743a0.json

And add the full path to the file

> GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="/root/path/to/Natural-Language-96a3b12743a0.json